# Compare a value againts values in a list vb.net/c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a value that is inserted by the user that i want to compare against a list of decimal values that i have coded in. I want to go through every value in that list to see if that value typed by the user is greater or less than that specific value in list and if so get the index of that list placement.

Could anyone help me out with this?

```
test.Text = values.IndexOf(user_textbox.Text)
```

I converted the code to vb.net and did some adjustments to it

```
For i As Decimal = 0 To values.Count - 1
   If user_textbox.Text > values(i) Then
      test.Text = values.IndexOf(i)
   End If
Next i
```

Sadly it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

```
// Put checks of course
var inputDecimal = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var decimalList = new List<decimal>()
{
    10m,
    2m,
    2m,
    10m
};

var foundList = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < decimalList.Count; i++)
{
    if (inputDecimal > decimalList[i] || inputDecimal< decimalList[i])
        foundList.Add(i);
}

// Print
foundList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Something like this?

Can be improved a lot i think, this is the base.

Comment: I converted the code to vb.net and did some adjustments to it

    For i As Decimal = 0 To values.Count - 1
       If user_textbox.Text > values(i) Then
          test.Text = values.IndexOf(i)
       End If
    Next i

Sadly it still doesn't work..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).